# New Project in Adobe Air

Tags: air

we are starting a new desktop project and we are evaluating adobe air as our development platform. this is because most our team are flex developers and we want to take advantage of that. but we have several question in order to decide whether or not to use air as a development platform.

- How recomended is to use a bridge to
  communicate with peripherals through
  serial and paralell ports.How can i
  communicate air application with my
  system database.
- There is a well known framework for
  object persistence, like hibernate
  ??. if not, what is the best approach.?
- Which are the best approach for our
  applications distribution, how can we
  deal with product key, product
  licenses, etc. What advantage do we
  have using AIR MarketPlace ?

  Any help you can provide me, to point me in right direction, i will appreciates

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- system communication via NativeProcesses (since Air 2.0)
- Air supports SQLite; from Air you can communicate via RPC or socktes with (for example) a JavaServer with Hibernate
- Air App Licensing with [Sharify](http://www.sharify.it/)

  Damian